# "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'" While importing Json

Tags: python, json, django

I get the following error when i try to use the "deleted" part of my json file to change one field (ReportedStatusField) for each "Facility" in my Database that matches with the id's inside "deleted":

```
  File "C:\users\management\commands\deactivate_facilities.py", line 42, in handle
    for key, data in data_object.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

It's basically a list of UUID's of Facilities that closed so i change the status this way with a json file that gets imported with a url.

```
import requests
import json

from users.models import Facility
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

IMPORT_URL = 'https://domain/file.json'

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def import_facility_from_file(self, data):
                    key = data.get('key', None)


                    if Facility.objects.filter(key=UUID):
                        
                        msg = "\n\nFacility closed: {}\n{}".format(key, str())
                        print(msg)
                        facility, facility_closed = Facility.objects.update_or_create(key=UUID,
                            defaults={
                            'ReportedStatusField': 'closed'
                            }
                        )                        

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.get(
            url=IMPORT_URL,
            headers=headers,
        )

        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()

        for key, data_object in data.items():
            if key in ["deleted"]:
                for key, data in data_object.items():
                    self.import_facility_from_file(data)
```

My JSON

```
{
"added":
{"125hk24h5kjh43k5":
{
"UUID":"125hk24h5kjh43k5",
"Name":"Test Facility 1",
"AddressInfo":
{"PrimaryAddress":"1234 Drive RD"},
"ImporterLastModifiedTimestamp":1643721420}},


// This is the "list" of deleted Facilities

"deleted":["235hk24h5kjh43k5,235hk345789h43k5"],

"modified":{"995hk24h5kjh43k5":
{
"UUID":"995hk24h5kjh43k5",
"Name":"Test Facility 2",
"AddressInfo":
{"PrimaryAddress":"2345 Test RD"},
"ImporterLastModifiedTimestamp":1643721420}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we use **'items'** method on the dictionary, it will return the tuple type element in the list.
and we cannot run 'item' method on the list

```
   for key, data_object in data.items():
            if key in ["deleted"]:
                for  data in data_object:
                    self.import_facility_from_file(data)
```